# Problem with retrieve Image in bad quality from Database

Tags: vb.net

When I choose image from Filedialog and put it Picturebox it seems ok But when after I save it and then retrieve it , it comes in very bad quality and background becomes Black .. so How i can Fix it ?

this is picture before I save into database:

[image]

and this picture After I retrieve it:

[image]

Here is my code for saving:

```
        Dim filename As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName + ".jpg"
        Dim Filesize As Int32
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Try
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            GoTo Resume_COde
        End Try

Resume_COde:
        Dim arrimage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
        Filesize = mstream.Length

        mstream.Close()
        CMD = New SqlCommand("Update setting_TBL set Image_Value=@p1 Where Setting_name=@p2", sqlcon)
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", arrimage)
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "Company_Logo")
```

and here is my Code for retrieving:

```
        Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select Image_Value From Setting_Tbl Where Setting_Name='Company_Logo'", sqlcon)
    Dim CMDB As New SqlCommandBuilder(Da)
    Da.Fill(DT)

    Dim picbyte() As Byte = DT.Rows(0).Item("Image_Value")
    Dim pic As New System.IO.MemoryStream(picbyte)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(pic)
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    pic.Close()
```

Comment: It looks bad because the image uses partially transparent pixels.  A feature that JPEG does not support.  Consider PNG instead.

Comment: It looks like there's an alpha channel associated with the image that isn't being properly saved or loaded. What you are displaying is the RGB channels but an alpha (transparency/opacity) channel would provide the anti-aliasing.

Comment: This: `Dim arrimage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()` is also wrong. You want `mstream.ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thank you it's Solved
I used .png instead of Jepg here

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

and .ToArray() instead .GetBuffer here

```
Dim arrimage() As Byte = mstream.ToArray()
```

Thank you All
is there any Other Recommended ?